# Como alterar a posição de uma Default Ribbon do Sharepoint 2013

Tags: xml, sharepoint

Estou tentando alterar a posição da Default Ribbon Attach File(Anexar Arquivo) para um grupo que criei na aba "Editar" de uma lista, porem so consigo fazer com que ele fique oculto adicionando essa linha de codigo ao meu Element.xml

```
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.AttachFile" />
```

O que eu deveria mudar para alterar a posição dele?